# How to convert to ASCII format under OpenWrt?

Tags: linux, openwrt

https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=eNk7b4fj

Dear Community!

under Fedora 14 - Bash:
`$ cat asdf | iconv -c -t ASCII`
`<a href="http://www.net-security.org/secworld.php?id=10607">biometric cabinet lock detects life in the finger</a>`
`ASDF`
`$` 

under OpenWrt 10.03 - Ash: 
`root@router01:~# cat asdf`
`<a href="http://www.net-security.org/secworld.php?id=10607">biometric cabinet lock detects �life in the finger�</a>`
`ASDF`
`root@router01:~# cat asdf | iconv -c -t ASCII`
`-ash: iconv: not found`
`root@router01:~#`

But theres no iconv under OpenWrt.

Are there other working methods to convert a piped ( "|" ) text to *only ascii* format (under OpenWrt 10.03)?

Thank you!

Comment: "Install iconv" comes to mind...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cY09WEp1

Answer (score 1):

Well. you can use cat -v to output it as escaped character. if there are only a few of those character you need to convert, you can use `sed` to substitute it out

http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/108/beware-of-non-ascii-characters/

Alternatively, use `tr`

http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/linux-unix/how-remove-non-printable-ascii-characters-file-unix

Comment: thank you for trying to help, but it doesn't work..: https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kyVSd9Wv - maybe because of busybox is faulty

Comment: the cat that ships with busybox isn't as sophisticated as the one in ubuntu... eh... sorry. i'll try another shot in a while